# Regex for Numeric only or Empty

Tags: c#, regex

So I have this regex validation for MVC. It only allows numeric but it also prevent empty field. I want it to only allows numeric but also allows empty field. Any help will be appreciated

```
[RegularExpression("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Must be number")]
[RequiredIfEmpty("Phone", ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block in the end

```
...[0-9]+
```

requires at least one digit to be presented.

You can capture the whole fraction part with point to `?`.

Try this one:

```
[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?
```

Note that `\` will become escaped `\\` in C#.